# are wifi upload and download speeds symmetric?

Tags: wireless-networking

I am trying to figure out whether my upload speed is limited by the WiFi speed (distance from the hotspot) or by the provider link.  The computer is pretty far from the wifi hotspot; I am getting 20Mbps down and 5Mbps up.  Is it possible that 5Mbps is result of a weaker antenna in the laptop and I might get a big boost by laying ethernet cable or is it more likely that this is just the speed limit that Verizon is giving us?

Comment: How are you testing this connection? Are you copying files between two computers or are you using an Internet speed test website? [Why upload rates are lower than download rates in normal internet connections?](https://superuser.com/questions/914/why-upload-rates-are-lower-than-download-rates-in-normal-internet-connections)

Comment: internet speed test.

Comment: Then this is likely a feature of your internet connection and nothing to do with your WiFi. Almost all modern internet connections have this kind of limit and your ISP should have told you your expected speeds when purchasing the connection. Faster download than upload is normal for internet connections.

Comment: I know that upload/download are asymmetrical at the ISP level.   The question is whether there is similar asymmetry in WiFi.  @Mokubai closing this was very strange.  My question is completely different than your understanding of it.

Answer (score 2):

ISP bandwidth, in particular for DSL, is nearly always asymmetric, with less upload bandwith and more download bandwidth.

Wifi is nearly always symmetric, because a worse antenna in your laptop will also mean worse reception.

Most ISP routers have a page in their GUI where you can see what upload and download bandwidth your provider gives you.

Comment: So that part about reception and transmission is not clear to me.  Intuitively, sender matters more... I think m.b. I should ask this on physics stackexchange :)

Comment: @MK01 "senders" matter far less than you think in long distance links outside of your home as most home users are "consumers" of Internet content rather than senders by a large degree. You do not mention whether the test you performed is internal to your home (between your own computers) or if you used some Internet speed test tool.

Comment: @MK01 You can certainly ask this on the physics stackexchange, but physics of EM waves is symmetric - if you calculate the gain/loss between antennas, it makes no difference of you go from antenna A to B, or in the reverse direction. There is asymmetry in the electronics (amplifiers) in the sending/receiving paths, however, but I'd assume them to be of similar quality just for costs reasons.

Comment: Do you have any links that discuss this?  I couldn't find any reliable source...

Comment: So ask on the physics stackexchange; I am sure they can give you links. I'd have to google myself (because it's something I learned at university from books, so I don't have links).

Answer (score 1):

WiFi doesn't have the same limitations, but will have different ones based on the antennae of your machines and router and the supported speeds of the WiFi modules themselves.

20 or 5Mbps is going to be an ISP limit and not a WiFi one.

Modern WiFi should, with a good signal, be getting somewhere above 100Mbps or higher and for the most part will be symmetric unless there is interference from other networks or devices nearby.

You might get a better connection *between machines on your own network* by changing to Ethernet, but it is unlikely to affect their connection to the internet by any significant degree.